# While loop for odd or even

Tags: javascript, html

Ask user for a number. Determine if the number is even or odd. I have my constants set and using modulo to figure this out. However I am stuck in an infinite loop and can't figure out why. I have my if statement in the loop as well as a break statement to get out, but still in an infinite loop.

*HAVE TO USE A WHILE LOOP*

```js
// declare constants
const MODULO = 2;
const EVEN = 0;
const ODD = 1;

// declare variables
var enteredNumber;
var result;

// prompt user to enter an even number
enteredNumber = prompt("Enter an even number: ");

// convert user input into a number
enteredNumber = Number(enteredNumber);

// determine result of modulo equation
result = enteredNumber % MODULO;

// while loop to check if enteredNumber is even or odd
while (result === EVEN) {
  document.write(enteredNumber + " is an even number <br/>");
  enteredNumber = prompt("Enter an even number: ");
  enteredNumber = Number(enteredNumber);
  result = enteredNumber % MODULO;

  if (result === ODD) {
    document.write(enteredNumber + " isn't an even number");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code looks okay and works for me. What's a condition that causes an infinite loop?

Comment: Code is working fine as written, Any behavior you are expecting and couldnt achieve ?

Comment: It works fine on here but through the html file on the browser, it is an infinite loop that keeps prompting the user to enter an even number. Doesn't get to the displaying results portion of the code

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially one-liner this thing. You're already checking stuff with the `while`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    while (!(parseInt(window.prompt('Enter an even number', '2') || '1', 10) % 2)) { };
});
```

**Why this works**

Javascript has 'falsy' and 'truthy' values.

`window.prompt('Enter an even number', '2')`

This code prompts the user for a number. The result is a string (or null, if the user blanks out the prompt).

`<a string or null> || '1'`

If the user blanked out the prompt, it will return `null`. In Javascript we can use the **or** operator to choose between two things. `null || '1'` reads from left to right. The first thing is falsy so it chooses `'1'`.

If the user entered a number (like 10), we would get the number they entered **as a string.**

Then we parse the string to a number with `parseInt`.

Take that result and use the **modulo** operator `%` to divide by the operand and return the *remainder*. When you divide by 2 the remainder will either be `0` or `1`. These are falsy/truthy values.

`while(0)` evaluates to false and breaks the loop. `while(1)` evaluates to true and continues the loop.

Comment: This works. However I haven't learned some of these terms in my class and are required to only use what we have been taught and not any outside code yet.